# "writer of" vs "writer for"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, collocations

Cited from [writer (noun) page on Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/writer?q=writer):

> the **writer of** this letter

> a freelance feature **writer for** ‘Time’ magazine

In what situations is "writer of" or "writer for" used?

Comment: In the first, the person has written the letter. In the second, the person has written some articles _for_ the magazine - _writer of_ would imply that they write the whole magazine on their own!

Comment: You are a *writer for* something when you contribute individual things to the whole; one is a *writer for* Time. You are a *writer of* individual things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Kate Bunting and @FeliniusRex, who provide following comments which should answer this question.

> In the first, the person has written the letter. In the second, the person has written some articles for the magazine - writer of would imply that they write the whole magazine on their own! – Kate Bunting

> You are a writer for something when you contribute individual things to the whole; one is a writer for Time. You are a writer of individual things. – FeliniusRex